# Stuck at LearnPython.org Tutorial(Regarding Modules)

Tags: python, module

I'm stuck on an exercise at LearnPython.org regarding Modules and Packages. The questions says:

**In this exercise, you will need to print an alphabetically sorted list of all functions in the `re` module, which contain the word `find`.**

I have absolutely no clue where to start. Do i loop through the module list? Is that even possible? (Sorry if i sound clueless, new to Python)

**Given Code:**

```
import re

# Your code goes here
```

**Expected Output:**

```
['findall', 'finditer']
```

Comment: Start with: `dir(re)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three parts to this lesson: reflection, filtering, and lambdas/or list comprehension with filters.

First you need to get a list of methods & attributes via reflection: `dir(obj)`.

Then you need to filter; there are at least two ways here (and use IPython as a shell, it's your friend):

```
In [3]: filter(lambda a: 'find' in a, dir(re))
Out[3]: ['findall', 'finditer']

In [4]: [a for a in dir(re) if 'find' in a]
Out[4]: ['findall', 'finditer']
```

Comment: Good solutions, but you have to assume according to the LearnPython.org tutorial that List Comprehensions and Lambda's have not been taught yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting with the [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) function.

Comment: That was the first thing that came to my mind but the OP's question was to list all the functions, but `dir()` gives back all the attributes including a lot of non-functions.  It turns out not to matter in this particular question since `find` and `findAll` are both functions.

Comment: @Ray: `callable(lambda : 1)` ---> `True`

Comment: Thanks guys, i managed to solve my own question. Simply used a for loop to loop through each item in re with the first 4 letters[:4] as "find", and appended each item to an empty list. I used the for loop, because the tutorial assumes i haven't learnt List comprehensions and Lambdas. I'll post the solution, once my '7 hour answer my own question limit' gets removed.

Comment: `ans = sorted([x for x in dir(re) if callable(getattr(re, x)) and 'find' in x])`